# How to export PGF/TikZ to HTML5/web?

Tags: tikz-pgf, html, latex2html

For everyone who knows and loves PGF/TikZ: Is there something that has a similar powerful expressive high-level “graphic description language” like TikZ for HTML5?

I want to convert high-level textual descriptions of drawings (e.g. TikZ) to web-readable material.

Should have:

- something like PGF/TikZ’s \node
- with easy placement relative to each other: `\node (bla) [right=of othernode]`
- useful anchors for drawing “connections” between things, bla.north, bla.north_west, bla.360
- styles
- powerful coordinate systems, calculations and transformations
- labels: in the nodes and next to paths
- and: simple links (click → webpage)

I don’t care about:

- animation
- dragging
- changing shapes
- or any other interaction/dynamics more than links
- (not that they would bother me, I just don’t need them)

Probably something like this:

- Syntax might be JavaScript
- build on top of HTML5 canvas/SVG
- but a PGF/TikZ export to PNGs *with* HTML imagemaps would do it, too. :-)
- other ideas?

Invalid is:

- SVG as both: the description language and the output format in one

SVG is simply not a high level human-readable/-edible language. I know that XML’s design goal was to be human-readable. But in practice it is not. – SVG as the output format is fine, but doesn’t answer the question yet.

TikZ-export is not off-topic, so re-open this question!

Comment: It’s obviously a cross-topic question. I need to ask people who know both: PGF and the answer to my question (or suggestions). If you don’t belong to these, no need to clutter my question with useless comments. What are the chances that someone with TikZ knowledge has heard of HTML? 100%. And the chances of someone who is professional with websites knows PGF? 0.01%. I even guess that the absolute number of people who know both is higher here then on stackexchange. – Consider this a convert question: How to turn a TikZ picture with hyperlinks into HTML? I’m even willing to rewrite the code. Ok?

Comment: @RobertSiemer: For generating HTML/SVG output with TikZ, take a look at section 10.2.4 *Producing HTML / SVG Output* of the manual.

Comment: You are approaching the comments from the wrong way. HTML supports SVG graphics elements why would you create a TikZ picture when you have HTML5? You can create your pictures on any wyswyg software, get the output and do your magic on it. Typesetting documents is a different ball game and SVG etc is not straightforward to use where TikZ shines.

Comment: You can convert your fancy TikZ pictures into `svg`, e.g. with [`dvisvgm`](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/). It also has basic support for hyperlinks, and every modern browser renders `svg`.

Comment: @Jake, `latex` fails when I set the the driver to pgfsys-tex4ht.def – did you ever try that `tex4ht` (looks old!)?

Comment: @Alex, dvisvgm download page says it’s in Ubuntu’s texlive-extra-utils package, which it isn’t (check from Lucid to Trusty). I try later this week.

Comment: @RobertSiemer It is in texlive-binaries, but the hyperref features were added only recently, so you may want build from source anyway. (It's easy.)

Comment: @percusse, did you really mean to say that direct SVG, direct canvas, etc. are not so nice to use compared to TikZ??? – That is exactly the reason for this question! (What I don’t understand is: why does your comment get upvotes and my question less...)

Comment: I meant HTML5 is way more powerful than TikZ. You can create your SVG figures with a much more powerful syntax. Why would you put TikZ in between and lower expectations. That's why I think this is off-topic because we can't solve an HTML problem using TikZ unless you can help us with the conversion tool.

Comment: @percusse, nobody seriously writes large SVG graphics by hand (keyboard). – That’s a discipline where SVG never gets into. TikZ is the best language I know in that area (with the highest level of expression and abstractions which scale well even for the largest drawings). – And this question is about how to use this awesome tool (TikZ) in the web. – I’m actually open to hear about better tools for this very purpose (describing drawings in a close-to-human language), but SVG is unfortunately not one of them.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Take a look http://www.creativebloq.com/design/examples-svg-7112785 and also this one as a comparison http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp (by the way I never said you'll program SVG by hand, but I'm hoping to convince you that SVG is a superset of TikZ abilities in which you really type by hand)

Comment: @percusse, I don’t understand your “superset” thing. – Are you trying to convince me that you can do awesome stuff where SVG is involved? No need, I know. But that is not my topic. – I want to textually describe a diagram and show it in the web. TikZ allows for readable descriptions, and SVG does not. See your second link (w3schools): a simple star is the result of two unreadable lines of SVG. – Is there any nice textual description language which can output those ugly lines?

Comment: @RobertSiemer see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172628/2891 for example of converting tikz to svg with some elements added. It should be easy to add hyperlinks this way

Comment: It's not that complicated. Try the same star in TikZ with the fill. Besides, who will convert the TikZ path to SVG? Javascript? Something else? If your question to this is not TeX then it is unfortunately off-topic.

Comment: @percusse, you’re wrong with your simplification of what is on-topic. Related tools (e.g. converters from TikZ to whatever) are on-topic as mentioned in the [help pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Note that there are no conversion tools on the help pages. We had many questions about MS Word etc. Also writeLaTeX and shareLaTeX questions are also off-topic which are much more related than TikZ conversion tools. Main reason as I mentioned is that they require knowledge other than TeX.

Comment: @percusse, well, it says “related software and tools”. And `dvisvgm` is the answer to my question. – Unfortunately @Alex is not able to cash any credit for it as my question got closed...